# Equivalence relation class $\bar{0}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

In the set $\mathbb{Z}$ we define the following relation:

$$a\Re b \iff a\equiv \bmod2\text{ and }a\equiv \bmod3$$

1)Prove that $\Re$ is an equivalence relation. (Done)

2) Describe the equivalence class $\bar{0}$. How many different equivalence classes exist?

My thought on $\bar{0}$ is :

$$\bar{0} =  a \in \mathbb{Z} / a\Re b \implies a\equiv 0\bmod2\text{ and }a\equiv 0\bmod3$$

Comment: Can you describe that set in plain English, rather than formulas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thoughts?: exactly.

Now, $a \equiv 0 \pmod 2 $ and $a \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \implies a \equiv 0 \pmod 6$.

So, the equivalence class of $\bar{0}$ is equal to the set of all integer multiples of $6$: $$\bar{0} = \{6k\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$$

Can you see that the equivalence classes of $\Re$ are the residue classes, modulo $6$?

Comment: How comes $a\equiv 0mod6$ ? The modulo relation means that $a - 0 = 6k $, so I get $a = 6k$ which represents the total of the points that belong to the above line?

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Just a tiny question, what is the total number of equivalence relations?

Comment: There are six equivalence classes. Those integers that are equivalent to $0$, mod 6; those that are equivalent to 1, mod 6;  to 2; to 3; to 4; and those that are equivalent to 5 mod 6.

Comment: @amWhy: What nice feedback +1